# Safely adding a schema via cfquery

Tags: t-sql, coldfusion, cfquery

I want to be able to add an SQL schema via `<cfquery>`. I know this is not safe:

```
<cfquery dataSource="#form.datasource#">
    CREATE SCHEMA [#form.schema#] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
</cfquery>
```

And this throws and error:

```
<cfquery dataSource="#form.datasource#">
    CREATE SCHEMA <cfqueryparam CFSQLType="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.schema#"> AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
</cfquery>
```

And stored procedures are not an option. They are not an option because the stored procedure should be a part of the schema, which doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only "not safe" if you don't verify it's safe before using it. I imagine you'd be fine if you simply validate that `form.schema` value to be a sequence of safe characters and nothing else? That's a simple regex: `^\w+$` (allows for A-Z, 0-9, and underscore).

And you can't use a `<cfqueryparam>` as those are for parameter values, not random bits of the SQL statement. Ref: "[What one can and cannot do with `<cfqueryparam>`](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/07/what-one-can-and-cannot-do-with.html)"